# Prevent Internet Explorer from loading external entities including w3 DTD

Tags: internet-explorer, resources

I am accessing a remote HTML resource that is returned after XSLT processing and has a header like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html xmlns:..
```

and every version of Internet Explorer in several locations that I've tried tries to load the DTD from the w3.org website and that resource has a 15sec artificial delay. Is there a way to make Internet Explorer not load this external entity?

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/f9a70df4-195e-4604-a70d-775052d9596b/ie7-not-opening-xml-files?forum=itprovistaie did not make a difference, that is to say, registering the dll made no appreciatable difference, disabling all addons doesn't work in the way described with IE11 it seems but as all  (and different) machines I've tried this from behaves in the same way it seems more a default behaviour of IE(the same goes for redundant registry keys): to load, at least this type of, external entities.

Chrome and FF do not appear to share this behaviour.

I may have a chance to change the remote resource to either keep this DTD local or not refer to it but the chance.

Comment: I personally don't like Internet explorer, but in the HTML world, these days you can use a simple `<!doctype HTML>` to indicate that the page is HTML5. I'm not sure how Internet Explorer will respond but Microsoft made a new browser called Edge I believe and I think Internet Explorer (all versions) will become obsolete soon.